# Combining two active records of same model and call some method on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application i have a class method in model which is combining two records

models/Client.rb

```
def self.get_clients
 account = params[:user].current_account
 account.clients + account.companies.map(&:clients).flatten
end
```

In controller i am using this method and applying kaminari paging on it

```
   def index
    Client.get_clients(params.merge(user: current_user)).page(params[:page]).per(10).unarchived
   end
```

I am getting this error

```
undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xb6743220>
```

How can i convert this array to an active record ? or is there some other way to combine these records?

Comment: some information about your schema might help. I guess a scope using a  `UNION` SQL query could do the trick.

Comment: clients can be associated with both account or companies. so in the listing i want show all clients associated with account and companies. Thats why i have concatenated these records

Comment: what is the exact nature of your associations ? Could you post the `belongs_to` / `has_many` definitions ? It is hard to build an accurate answer without this.

Comment: as a side note, instead of `account.companies.map(&:clients).flatten` you can do `account.companies.sum([], &:clients)`

Comment: @MarianTheisen but the result will still be considered as Array. I need an active record to call .page() method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :for_account, ->( account ){
     companies_account_id = Company.arel_table[:account_id]
     accounts_id             = Account.arel_table[:id]

     # 'uniq' is ActiveRecord's "SELECT DISTINCT"
     # the where clause is Arel for "companies.account_id = ? OR accounts.id = ?"
     uniq                   
       .joins( :company, :account )
       .where( 
         companies_account_id.eq( account.id ).or( accounts_id.eq(account.id) ) 
       )
   }

 end
```

and then in your controller :

```
@clients = Client.for_account( current_user.current_account )
```

Comment: Relation of account, company and client is like this  
**Account:**    
'has_many :clients, :through => :company_entities'  
'has_many :companies'  
**Company:**  
  'has_many :clients, :through => :company_entities'  
  'belongs_to :account'  
**Client:**    
'belongs_to :company'